# What is the difference between these sentences-usage and structural?

Tags: comparison

> There are no tanks to draw/take the water.
>
> There are no tanks to draw the water from.
>
> There are no tanks from which to take the water.

I want to know what is the difference between the usage of these, especially 2nd and 3rd. Another same type:

> No teachers to take the result from.
>
> No teachers from whom to take the result.

(**There are** has been omitted).

Comment: An old rule (not usually considered valid any more) is that sentences should not end in a preposition. So your last two example pairs simply restructure the sentences to form a "normal" prepositional phrase. The restructuring does not change meaning, but in some people's eyes makes them more grammatical. Peter answers your other questions.

Comment: 1 I want to know who he is. 2 I want to know who is he. Do they mean the same thing? Which one is preferred @RichF?

Comment: The first is preferred because the second is using a question form (who is he?) in a sentence which is not a question. #2 is thus grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are no tanks to draw the water from.
>   There are no tanks from which to take the water.

a difference between your two sentences is that "draw water" is an old term which is usually used to describe getting water from a well, not usually from something as modern as a "tank".  "Take" could be used for either situation, however both phrasings would be understood.

In your second set of sentences, the phrasing is usually

> No teachers to **get** the result from.
>   No teachers from whom to **get** the result.

since usually results are "given" by teachers or people in authority and not "taken".

Comment: I agree with Peter, the word **draw** -- though we understand it, is not really used like this any longer. **The water was *drawn* from the tank, through the pipe to the tap.**  Now we'd probably say, "The water comes from the tank, through the pipes to the tap."

Comment: Peter, I have a minor quibble. The word **tank** has a usage, that while archaic in many places, is still common in Texas and Oklahoma. It refers to what most of us would call a pond, but is usually man-made and is used to store water. [Texas Primer: The Stock Tank](http://www.texasmonthly.com/the-culture/texas-primer-the-stock-tank/) Thus "drawing water from a tank" is not necessarily anachronistic.

Comment: Curious if **tank** retained similar usage elsewhere, I found [Irrigation tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrigation_tank) at the Wikipedia. This seems to be from India.

Comment: **tanks** are vessels used to hold water, e.g. "water tank", is used often enough, if you drive down the highway in the US you may see water tanks / towers which look like golf balls on a golf tee. However, one would not usually say *draw water from the tank* these days, usually **get**, "get water from the tank" will suffice.  In the case of Stock Tanks, the "tanks" are stationary and the cattle must go to the tank.

Comment: 1 I want to know who he is. 2 I want to know who is he. Do they mean the same thing? Which one is preferred?

Comment: Is the very first sentence incorrect?-There are no tanks to take the water.

Comment: "There are no tanks to take the water" means "there are no tanks to **store**/**put** water". if you mean to fetch water, it would usually be said "There are no tanks to get *(the)* water *(from)*." Not sure why nonnatives so frequently use **take** as in "I will **take** some water" when a native will say "I will **have** some water".